# How to insert text into specific line in textarea with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have this HTML code:

```
<textarea>
line 1 text
line 2 text
line 3 text
line 4 text
line 5 text
</textarea>
```

How can I insert text after the third line, so my result is this:

```
<textarea>
line 1 text
line 2 text
line 3 text
this is my new text here!!!!!!!!!
line 4 text
line 5 text
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a function that takes your text and a line number, splits the current text within the box by the new line character, add in the new text, and update the textarea box.

```
function addLine(text, line) {
  let ta = document.querySelector("textarea"), 
  split_text = ta.textContent.split(/\n/gmi);

    if (line <= split_text.length - 1) split_text.splice(line - 1, 0, text);
    else split_text.push(text);
  ta.textContent = split_text.join("\n");
}

addLine("This is my new text here!", 3);
addLine("This is another example!", 7);
addLine("And one more!", 2);
```

```js
function addLine(text, line) {
let ta = document.querySelector("textarea"), 
split_text = ta.textContent.split(/\n/gmi);

  if (line <= split_text.length - 1) split_text.splice(line - 1, 0, text);
  else split_text.push(text);
  ta.textContent = split_text.join("\n");
}

addLine("This is my new text here!", 3);
addLine("This is another example!", 7);
addLine("And one more!", 2);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
line 1 text
line 2 text
line 3 text
line 4 text
line 5 text</textarea>
```

Comment: and you lost line 2 and line 3

Answer (score 3):

Just `.split` the `.val` on new line, splice in your new text, and set the value to the `.join`'d value:

```js
let line = 3;
let val = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
val.splice(line - 1, 1, 'new text');
$('textarea').val(val.join('\n'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="height: 70px">
line 1 text
line 2 text
line 3 text
line 4 text
line 5 text
</textarea>
```

Comment: This is the right answer. I got to the same one after I understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I thought you needed to replace the line, not insert a new one.
Here is a new answer based on the same one.

```js
// get the value and split it into lines.
var linesArr = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
var indexToInsertAt = 3;
// Insert an new element at the index you want
linesArr.splice(indexToInsertAt, 0, "this is my new text here!!!!!!!!!");
// replace the value with the new string (after you add the new line char again)
$('textarea').val(linesArr.join('\n'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea cols="50" rows="20">
line 1 text
line 2 text
line 3 text
line 4 text
line 5 text
</textarea>
```

Comment: Great that you solved the OP's problem. But you could improve it by adding an explanation.

Comment: this doesn't even solve it, in the example provided the line does not get overwritten, there is text inserted between lines

Comment: @dave you are correct, I did misunderstood the question, correcting it now

Answer (score 0):

following the comments in my example you should understand how it works:

```js
// get a reference to the jq node
var t = $('textarea')

// get the org str
var orgStr = t.val()

//manipulate the string splitting every line as an array item
var arr = orgStr.split('\n')

//add 'stuff' on line 3
arr.splice(2,0,'stuff')

//join the array and use it 
t.val(arr.join('\n'))
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 400px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
line 1 text
line 2 text
line 3 text
line 4 text
line 5 text
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you out, use [**`.split()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to convert an array of all lines and then use [**`.splice()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to add to your desired index a new line and then [**`.join()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) again to supply back to the textarea with the updated text.

```js
function addLine(textarea, lineNo, line) {

  var lines = textarea.val().split('\n');

  lines.splice(lineNo, 0, line);
  textarea.val(lines.join('\n'));
}

$("#add").on('click', function() {
  var textarea = $("textarea");
  var totalLines = textarea.val().split('\n').length;
  var line = $("#line").val();
  var lineNo = $("#line_no").val();

  var inputNotEmpty = line !== '' && lineNo !== '';
  var validLineNum = (lineNo <= totalLines && lineNo >= 0);

  if (inputNotEmpty) {
    if (validLineNum) {
      addLine(textarea, lineNo, line);
    } else {
      console.log('Provide a valid Line number');
      setTimeout('console.clear()', 2000);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('New Line Text and New Line Number both are required');
    setTimeout('console.clear()', 2000);
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="50" rows="10">line 1 text
line 2 text
line 3 text
line 4 text
line 5 text</textarea>
<br/>
<p>Add "0" as line number to add in the start of the textarea</p>
<button id="add">add line after</button>
<input id="line_no" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter line number" />
<input id="line" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter new line text" />
```

Comment: ummm what did i do wrong ? please leave comment when downvoting so i could correct myself

Comment: idk why someone downvoted you, but i upvoted to cancel it out since this solves it

Comment: I appreciate that @dave i was thinking maybe i did something wrong that i cant see

Comment: i think someone is on down voting spree again.